# Drawing separate lines on a Matplotlib canvas and writing coordinates to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, canvas

I took the solution from here: [matplotlib onclick event repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975105/matplotlib-onclick-event-repeating)

I want to change this code so when I click the canvas twice, the line is finished on the second click. The third click should be the first point of a completely new line rather than a continuation.

Also, is there any way to write the coordinates of x,y and x1,y1 of each line that is created to a dataframe?

code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Plot some random data
#values = np.random.rand(4,1);
#graph_1, = ax.plot(values, label='original curve')
graph_2, = ax.plot([], marker='o')

# Keep track of x/y coordinates
xcoords = []
ycoords = []

def onclick(event):
    xcoords.append(event.xdata)
    ycoords.append(event.ydata)

    # Update plotted coordinates
    graph_2.set_xdata(xcoords)
    graph_2.set_ydata(ycoords)

    # Refresh the plot
    fig.canvas.draw()
    
    

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

coords = []
current_coords = []


def onclick(event):
    global current_coords
    if event.inaxes:
        current_coords.append((event.xdata, event.ydata))
        if len(current_coords) == 2:
            ax.plot([current_coords[0][0], current_coords[1][0]],
                    [current_coords[0][1], current_coords[1][1]], 'ro-')
            coords.append([current_coords[0], current_coords[1]])
            current_coords[:] = []

        # Refresh the plot
        fig.canvas.draw()


cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
print(coords)
```

the variable `coords` contains a list of coordinates. Each item is a list `[(x0,y0),(x1,y1)]`

**EDIT**
This version of the code only shows one line, and responds to both mouse clicks and pressing the 'a' key on the keyboad

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

coords = []
current_coords = []
l, = ax.plot([], [], 'ro-')


def onclick(event):
    global current_coords
    if event.inaxes:
        current_coords.append((event.xdata, event.ydata))
        if len(current_coords) == 2:
            l.set_data([current_coords[0][0], current_coords[1][0]],
                       [current_coords[0][1], current_coords[1][1]])
            coords.append([current_coords[0], current_coords[1]])
            current_coords[:] = []

        # Refresh the plot
        fig.canvas.draw()


def onkey(event):
    if event.key == 'a':
        onclick(event)


cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
cid2 = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onkey)
plt.show()
print(coords)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works great. Is it possible to make the line vanish after each new line, but the coordinates are still stored?

Comment: Also, if I wanted to replace the click with a letter would it be as simple as adding if event.button == "a"? Thanks